# Google fonts displaying bold in Firefox and IE

Tags: fonts

I am using Google fonts on a website I am making but they are displaying very thick in Firefox and IE. The fonts are Domine and Source Sans Pro. Domine (the header) isn't too different in thickness but Source Sans Pro (body text) looks bold in comparison to Chrome.

The top portion of the screenshot is Chrome and the bottom is Firefox and IE (it displays identically on both browsers.) Any clue as to what is going on here and how I can fix it?

Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OJLc.jpg

Comment: Do they appear different on the website (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Domine) as well? Also, can you please provide any code that may be of interest to solving this problem?

Comment: I just opened up Source Sans Pro on the Google fonts website in both Chrome and Firefox and sure enough it displays exactly the same as on my site. It's much bolder in Firefox. I'm assuming this means that the font is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue, specifically on Mac Firefox... The font Muli from Google fonts rendered beautifully Chrome and Safari, but Firefox had imposed a 'faux' bold (regardless of base font-weight being set at 400)

Here is what solved it for me. Add the following to your base typography css file:

`-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;`

There is more information in this CSS-Tricks.com forum discussion: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/typekit-fonts-much-bolder-in-firefox/page/3/

While the forum discussion title specifically mentions Typekit fonts, the solution applied beautifully to google fonts.

Comment: I had the same problem just now, your fix worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: So glad it was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with each browser's rendering implementation is different. That's why you get slightly different results and you are pretty much stuck with it.

However [this blog](http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold) suggests you should try including extra CSS3 `@font-face` rules or use the `font-synthesis` property.

Another solution might be using Flash, images, PDF or use (and test in different browsers!) the standard fonts.

Good luck!

Comment: Howie - great article on faux font bolding, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add character sets to your code.

When you choose the font from Google fonts, **add character sets** you need on your website, before you copy the code:

> 2. Choose the character sets you want:
>      Cyrillic Extended (cyrillic-ext)Latin (latin)Greek Extended (greek-ext)Greek (greek)Vietnamese (vietnamese)Latin Extended (latin-ext)Cyrillic (cyrillic)

If you need Latin, for example, after font name (and font styles) add **&subset=latin,latin-ext**.
Code would look like this:

> http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MyFont&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Hope this helps!